# PHP class with single variable

Tags: php

I'm using this PHP code for creating PHP class with default single variable.
But it's not work perfectly.

`Note` : I need to store data in single variable.

```
<?PHP

class hello
{
    public $data;
}

$test = new hello();

$test->data->user1->name = "Charan";
$test->data->user1->sex  = "male";
$test->data->user1->age  = "25";

$test->data->user2->name = "Kajal";
$test->data->user2->sex  = "female";
$test->data->user2->age  = "21";


print_r($test->data->user1);


?>
```

I got this error :

[image]

Please help me , how to fix it ?

Comment: How about using arrays instead of objects?

Comment: You didn't initialize `user1` and `user2`

Comment: @Shivan Raptor: ... and `data`

Comment: sorry i deleted my comment. its my fault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only declared the variable, but you havent set it up as a "type". For example youre trying to assign values to properties n an object... but `$data` is not an object - its not anything. You need to either assign an object to `$data` in the constructor for the class, or assign it from outside the class.

**Constructor**:

```
class hello
{
    public $data;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->data = new StdClass();

        // assuming you want the users set up here as well
        $this->data->user1 = new StdClass();
        $this->data->user2 = new StdClass();
    }
}
```

**From Outside:**

```
// assume we are use the same class definition from your orginal example
$test = new hello();
$test->data = new StdClass();
$test->data->user1 = new StdClass();
$test->data->user2 = new StdClass();

$test->data->user1->name = "Charan";
$test->data->user1->sex  = "male";
$test->data->user1->age  = "25";

$test->data->user2->name = "Kajal";
$test->data->user2->sex  = "female";
$test->data->user2->age  = "21";
```

Comment: "its not anything" --- it's actually not anything but `NULL`

Comment: oh! it's not make any effect... :-(

Comment: @user1882503: may be it's too early for objects then? How about **arrays**?

Comment: @zerkms: HA! I never thought they were actually `null`... Im used to seeing people define explicitly like `protected $something = null;` if they want it null so always figured there was a difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your class flexible, $data variable inside hello class must be an array.

For example:

```
<?php

class Person{

public $data = array();

function __construct(){}

}

$person = new Person();
$person->data['name'] = 'Juan Dela Cruz';

echo $person->data['name'];

?>
```

Comment: Why do you need an empty constructor?

Comment: Its a template from my editor, it creates a default empty constructor